# discord.py: sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 55, in <module>
    send_cal.start()
  File "python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 398, in start
    self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._loop(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 381, in create_task
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited
```

I get the above traceback with this code for my bot

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=20.0)
async def send_cal():
    message_channel = bot.get_channel(target_channel_id)
    print(f"Got channel {message_channel}")
    df = await someApi()

    df = df.drop(['stuff'], axis=1)
    csv = df.to_csv(header=False, index=False)
    res = csv.replace(',', ' ----> ')
    if (len(res)) >= 2000:
        await message.channel.send('result over 2000 chars')
    await message.channel.send(res)

@send_cal.before_loop
async def before():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")

send_cal.start()

client.run('mytoken')
```

I can't figure out why `send_cal` would never be awaited. I see in examples the same setup, where `.start()` kicks off the job and i assume asyncio is awaiting it under the hood, however i haven't been able to figure out why this is happening otherwise

edit: I am really just copying the starter guide here https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html

Answer (score 1):

figured it out -- needed to add `send_cal.start()` to the `on_ready` routine